# Simulate hosts file using iframe

Tags: html, iframe, dns, hosts

It appears Iframe doesn't pay attention to the hosts file on the server. For example:

```
123.45.67.890 randomwebsite.com
```

Would there be any simulate this behavior, for Iframe to resolve 123.45.67.890 to randomwebsite.com?
I'm open to absolutely any suggestions or workarounds! thanks

Comment: This is not the way that hosts file works. It translate a domain into an IP **not** an IP into a domain.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. An iframe does not do anything by itself, it is a passive element. It is the browser that does a name resolution where required, and that might or might not involve the `hosts` file on the client, depending on the client side setup which is out of your control.

Comment: oh ok thanks, so it is the browser of the person going to my webpage that does a name resolution, which would totally be out of my control? thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 0):

You should point your iframe to the domain name and let the hosts file on your local machine do the translation to the IP address. Other people will (need to) ask their DNS to do the translation from domain name to IP address.

DNS is a distrubuted system which you can influence by changing the DNS record (A) of your domain name at your domain name provider.